# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: iceberg. Issue when we are using Java Custom Catalog

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-iceberg

We are using a Java Custom Catalog with iceberg. The Table is created properly, however we get an issue when we insert the data.

```
    public String createCustomTable(String tableName) {
        try {
            TableIdentifier tableIdentifier = TableIdentifier.of(name(), tableName);
            Schema schema = readSchema(tableIdentifier);
            Map<String, String> properties = ImmutableMap.of(
                    TableProperties.DEFAULT_FILE_FORMAT, FileFormat.PARQUET.name()
            );
            PartitionSpec partitionSpec = PartitionSpec.builderFor(schema)
                    .identity(getPartitionKeyfromSchema(tableIdentifier.name()))
                    .build();
            String tableLocation = defaultLocation + tableIdentifier.namespace().toString() + "/" + tableIdentifier.name();
            catalog.createTable(tableIdentifier, schema, partitionSpec, tableLocation, properties);
            catalog.loadTable(TableIdentifier.of(name(), tableName));
            return "Table created";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }


    public String insertData(String tableName, String csvPath) throws IOException {
            Table icebergTable = catalog.loadTable(TableIdentifier.of(name(), tableName));
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .config("spark.master", "local")
                    .getOrCreate();
            String headerJson = readHeaderJson(tableName);
            LOGGER.info("Header JSON for {}: {}", tableName, headerJson);

            String[] columns = headerJson.split(",");
            Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                    .option("header", "false")
                    .option("inferSchema", "false")
                    .option("comment", "#")
                    .option("sep", "|")
                    .csv(csvPath)
                    .toDF(columns);
            LOGGER.info("Actual columns: {}", Arrays.toString(df.columns()));

            for (String col : df.columns()) {
                df = df.withColumn(col, df.col(col).cast("string"));
            }
            df.write().format("iceberg").mode(SaveMode.Append).save(icebergTable.location());
            LOGGER.info("Data inserted successfully into table: {}", tableName);
    }
```

When we execute this via a main program in Java it works perfectly

However when we create a jar out of this and call this from Spark it gives us this error

```
ERROR:root:Error: An error occurred while calling o0.insertData.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: iceberg. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:443)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:720)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:852)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
        at com.xyz.catalog.CustomCatalog.insertData(CustomCatalog.java:178)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: iceberg.DefaultSource
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:656)     
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:656)     
        at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:656)
        ... 16 more
```

We are trying to create and insert data in a iceberg table using a custom catalog.
We expect the insert to work properly

```
df.write().format("iceberg").mode(SaveMode.Append).save(icebergTable.location());
```

However we get an error

Comment: "*However we get an error*" What error?

Answer (score 0):

This error is lettting you know that the Datasource you are trying to use (`iceberg`) is not on the runtime classpath for Spark. This means you are probably not including the iceberg-spark-runtime package with your job submission.

An example of how to do this is shown in the [Getting Started Docs](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/getting-started/#using-iceberg-in-spark-3)

```bash
spark-shell --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.4.1
```

This would add the dependency to both the Driver and Executors of the Spark Job.

A similar packages arg should be added to your Spark Job submission or the corresponding property for your method of running Spark. See `spark.jars.packages` in the [Spark Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) For more info.

Comment: Thanks RussS for the quick response. It does not work with this either 

`spark-submit --master spark://spark:7077 /home/airflow/spark/app/my-module.py --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.4.1 `

Still gives me the error

Comment: That is an indication that there are probably other classpath issues, you can check the Spark UI Environment tab to see what jars are actually on the runtime classpath

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new session instead of using the existing session.

```py
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .config("spark.master", "local")
                    .getOrCreate();
```

Either replace that with

```py
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.getActiveSession();
```

Or if for whatever reason you need a new session then create it with [correct options](https://projectnessie.org/tools/iceberg/spark/#configuration):

```py
            SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                    .config("spark.master", "local")
                    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.2_2.12:1.4.1")
                    .getOrCreate();
```